# Django: ForeignKey vs related_name

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'd like to ask if there is an important distinction between below two ways of expressing a `ForeignKey` relation, or is it just a "style" difference?

It seems intuitive to first define parts and then collection of parts; a "sub-model" and then use this "parts-table" when populating a "main model". Thus, the `Album_1` model fetch a single or several tracks from the `Track_1` table (the collection consists of parts), as below.

**version_1**

```
class Track_1(models.Model):
    order = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    duration = models.IntegerField()

class Album_1(models.Model):
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     # if Album only holds one (1) track,
    tracks = models.ForeignKey(Track_1, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
     # if the "record"/"Album" holds several tracks
    tracks = models.ManyToManyField(Track_1, blank=True)
```

Meanwhile it is less intuitive to express it as below which verbally could be interpret as `Track_2` contains an `Album_2` (the part consist of a collection).

**version_2**

```
 class Album_2(models.Model):
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
 class Track_2(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album_2, related_name='tracks', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    duration = models.IntegerField()
```

I have seen this difference many times and I am curious why the seemingly unintuitive "version_2" is frequently used, e.g. in relation to Django Rest Framework?

Comment: Your version 1 and 2 are not equivalent. Version 1 has a one to many relationship from **Track** to **Album** whereas Version 2 has a one to many relationship from **Album** to **Track**. The basic need for a `related_name` is to access reverse relationships with (programmer) friendly names. Is `album_2.track_2_set` better or `album_2.tracks` better? The second one right?

Comment: Thanks, will adjust the question. The core I am getting at, why bother using "reverse relationships" when you can access them "forward"?

Comment: "Can access forward" does not mean anything about performance. Reverse name is a "trick" to ease the use of the ORM, but the field is not created in the database.

Comment: aha, now I get it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer here is what is pointed out in one of the comments by @Blusky, who writes:

> [...] Reverse name is a "trick" to ease the use of the ORM, but the
> field is not created in the database

Answer (score 2):

I would say that you mix the concepts: the Foreign Key defines the relationship between models, and the related_name is a property of the foreign key, that defines how you are going to reference the related model (it is mostly for convenience).

The important thing here is a Foreign Key because it defines the business logic of the app. I would say that the version_1 model is questionable from the business logic perspective, while the version_2 makes sense.

Let me explain, and I will start from the version 2:
In version_2 you are saying: my main model is Album, if I delete a particular album all the tracks from that album will be removed from the Track table. Makes sense!

In version_2 you are saying my main model is Track, if I delete a track from the Track table, all the Albums containing this particular track will be updated, because the track will be removed from all the Albums that contain it. Does it make sense? Maybe in some special cases yes, but in general it doesn't make sense.

Comment: hi, @alv2017, just reading it through, do you mean "In version_1 " in the fourth paragraph?